# Simon game why does the checkAnswer() work?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on the javaScript simon game.
From the code solution below, I understand most of the parts, except for the checkAnswer() part.

I understand that we first check if the color in the last of array matches, and then check for the length to ensure that the user has finished the sequence.

But, what I don't understand is why the code actually work without the need of an extra step of checking if both array matches?

For Example, if game pattern for round 4 is: [red, blue, yellow, green]
we first see if green matches, and then we check if the length matches, but where is the part that check whether the userClicked order is exactly the same as the game pattern?

```
var buttonColours = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];
var started = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).keypress(function () {
  if (!started) {
    $('#level-title').text('Level ' + level);
    nextSequence();
    started = true;
  }
});

$('.btn').click(function () {
  var userChosenColour = $(this).attr('id');
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
  playSound(userChosenColour);
  animatePress(userChosenColour);
  checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length - 1);
});

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
  if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
    if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        nextSequence();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    playSound('wrong');
    $('body').addClass('game-over');
    $('#level-title').text('Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart');

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('body').removeClass('game-over');
    }, 200);

    startOver();
  }
}

function nextSequence() {
  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $('#level-title').text('Level ' + level);
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

  $('#' + randomChosenColour)
    .fadeIn(100)
    .fadeOut(100)
    .fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColour);
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $('#' + currentColor).addClass('pressed');
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + currentColor).removeClass('pressed');
  }, 100);
}

function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio('sounds/' + name + '.mp3');
  audio.play();
}

function startOver() {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s checking on each button press, so prior presses have already been validated. If a prior press was incorrect you wouldn’t have gotten to the current one in the first place—the game would reset—so there’s no need to re-check the other values.